# jQuery selector on dynamic input value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, filter

How can you use the `:contain()` on an input field, e.g.

`#inputfield` contains a dynamic value of 5.938 and I want to use `$("#inputfield:contains('5.938')")`.

But that won't work, I've provided a demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NarutoDevil/ThFtt/).

I don't want to use `if(element.val() == '5.938')` because I need a provisional selector instead doing an `if/else` statement.

I also don't mean by using `[value=5.938]` because the value will change.

Comment: `:contains()` doesn't work simply because it's not intended for use with the `value` attribute. Do you need to do stuff anytime the input's value becomes `5.938`?

Comment: what is the scope which your code will run within (eg: a click handler, onchange, submit)?

Comment: Contains works for the value inside of an HTML dom element. **not** the value of an input element. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/ThFtt/2/

Comment: It would help if you could explain what the larger problem is that you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to [@Neal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413450/jquery-selector-on-dynamic-input-value/6413495#6413495), you need to use some sort of conditional. A simple selector won't work. [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) will suffice, however:

```
$('#inputfield').filter(function ()
{
    return $(this).val() == '5.938';
});
```

That said, it *looks* like you're using an ID selector, which can select at most one element, so `.filter()` is overkill — `if...else` really makes the most sense in that case.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
$("#inputfield:text[value*='"+dynamicValue+"']").length

//will select text input #inputfield with a value containing dynamicValue.
```

#### jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XEP4c/3/

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean, but you can test with this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XEP4c/

Comment: its the same as doing `$("#inputfield")`

Comment: Actually much simpler and cleaner solution then the selected answer. I wish I could upvote more to promote it.

Answer (score 1):

The answers here seem to get confusing as there isn't a clear explanation.  When you set the value dynamically like:

```
$('#inputfield').val('5.938')
```

It does not work to get the value using the selectors like:

```
$('#inputfield[value="5.938"]')
```

There are a few workarounds for this.  One is to use a filter:

```
var inputfield = $('#inputfield').filter(function () {
    return $(this).val() == '5.938';
});
if (inputfield.length) {
    alert("The input field has the value 5.938");
}
```

Or you could create your own selector:

```
(function($) {
    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
         val: function(el, i, attr) {
               return $(el).val() === attr[3];
         }
    });
}(jQuery));
if ($('#inputfield:val("5.938")').length) {
    alert("The input field has the value 5.938");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Manji's answer is simpler than the selected answer, although a simpler form again. I couldn't get this to work for me:

```
$("input[value='userID']").remove();
```

Concatenating the string to insert the dynamic variable works a treat instead though:

```
$("input[value='" + userID + "']").remove();
```

Obviously replace the .remove() with whatever you want to do with it.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the attribute selector:

```
$('#inputfield[value='+dynamicValue+']')
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle example isn't even trying to select an input field; your jQuery selector that uses `:contains` is selecting a `div`. Maybe I'm missing what you're trying to do here? You can most definitely inject a dynamic value in an attribute selector; it has nothing to do with jQuery, it's basic JS string functionality.

Comment: @reko_t -- try it out -- **it does not work**, attributes are **not** dynamic, properties are

Comment: @reko_t  it always shows `0` (i have no idea what browser shows otherwise)

Comment: @Neal: I'm using Firefox 4.0.1 on OS X and it always shows 1. Chrome 12.0.742.100 also shows 1 always. So does Safari Version 5.0.5 (6533.21.1). I'll be on Windows computer soon so I'll test my browser on it later and post results.

Comment: Hi, I just tested on FF 4.0.1 and Chrome 12.0.742.100 on Windows 7, and they both show `1`. I don't know what's up with you getting different results. However with further testing if I wrap the value in quotes, then both FF and Chrome results 0. For example see: http://jsfiddle.net/pAWCQ/ The first alert is always 1, and the second alert is always 0, in both FF and Chrome.

Comment: @reko_t -- both are `0` for me

Comment: I think I figured it out. Looking further in jQuery docs http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/ it says that the values should always be enclosed in quotes. However it works fine without quotes **if you use numerical** values, eg. try using `123` in the input box and it'll report `1`, but `foo` will report `0`. I only tried with numbers so that explains the difference. But since jQuery docs says you should always quote it, you're better off using the `.filter()` solution anyways.